# Passing accessToken obtained from github callback function across routes

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, passport.js, github-api

I have three files,

1. Auth.js

```
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
    clientID: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback",
    passReqToCallback: true,
  },
  function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    req.session.accessToken = accessToken;
}));
```

2. App.js

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.session());
app.use("/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/repo", repoRoute);
```

3. Repo.js

   Now, I want to use request.session.accessToken object in repo.js something like this

```
router.get('/abc', async function(req, res){
    req.session.accessToken; <- this is undefined for me
```

I have a frontend server in react, I included `credentials: true` for all requests but I still get an undefined value for req.session.accessToken.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined because the Github callback function only takes 4 arguments and it does not have req object in arguments. You can do something like this.

```js
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
    
    /* if profile does not have accessToken you can do like this
     *    profile.accessToken = accessToken
     */
     
      return done(null, profile);
    }
});


// Now this access token is available in req.user and you can store it to session like this 

app.get('/login', function(req, res, next){

  // regenerate session and add token
  
    req.session.regenerate(function (err) {
       if (err) next(err)
    
       req.session.accessToken = req.user.accessToken;

       // Now save the newly generated session.
       req.session.save(function (err) {
          if (err) return next(err)
          res.redirect('/')
      });

    });
 });
```

Comment: passReqToCallback: true, this flag adds req as well to the callback.

Comment: https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github/blob/master/lib/strategy.js

I don't see this flag here.

Comment: https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/delegated-authorization/

It is mentioned in this page, search for `passReqToCallback`